# wamp:display many "Strict standards"

Tags: wamp, standards, strict

I use wamp in my windows system and I download a cms about online shoping!when I install it,it displays many "Strict standards".but when I use other enveriment eg xampp,it display no errors and the install can run exactly!**is this the WAMP config error**,this confuses me very much!
the "Strict standards" that wamp displays like the following:

```
Strict standards: Non-static method ECMall::startup() should not be called statically in D:\wamp\www\ecmall1\install\index.php on line 18

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\wamp\www\ecmall1\eccore\controller\app.base.php on line 141
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting these errors is that you are running old PHP code on a up to date version of PHP.

You can turn these error messages off completely by editng the php.ini file

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini

change 
display_errors = On 
to 
display_errors = Off
```

Or just stop the strict errors being reported

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini

change 
error_reporting = E_ALL
To
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Comment: I try this and it wokrs!but when I use error_reporting() function in my PHP script,it doesn't work,it confuse me so much!

Comment: What are you doing with `error_reporting()`, remember that will override what you set in the `php.ini` file.